# each_value raising NoMethodError

Tags: ruby

I have some model in which I have the following code:

```
appraisal_detail.each_value { |detail|
  # some code...
}
```

It is raising NoMethodError with the message, "undefined method 'each_value'".  Am I doing anything wrong?  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Here is the full content of the method raising the error:

```
def self.update_appraisal_details(appraisal, appraisal_detail)
  status = true

  appraisal_detail_ids = appraisal.employee_appraisal_detail_ids

  appraisal_detail.each_value { |detail| 
    appraisal_detail = find_by_employee_appraisal_id_and_kra_list_id(appraisal.id, detail[:kra_list_id])

    if appraisal_detail.nil? # For newly added KRA
      new_detail = EmployeeAppraisalDetail.new(detail.merge({:employee_appraisal_id => appraisal.id}))
      status = (new_detail.save && status)
    elsif appraisal_detail.status == "Inactive" 
      status = (appraisal_detail.update_attributes(:status => "Active") && status)
      appraisal_detail_ids.delete(appraisal_detail.id)
    else 
      appraisal_detail_ids.delete(appraisal_detail.id)
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: What value is passed to `update_appraisal_details`?

Comment: Give the full error stack..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `Hash` object as `appraisal_detail`.

```
>> {1=>2}.each_value {|x| p x}
2
```

It seems like you are passing non-Hash object.

```
>> [].each_value { |x| p x }
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_value' for []:Array
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```